# Audiokit/swift newbie: AKOperationEffect array

Tags: audiokit

I can't find a way to declare an array of `AKOperationEffect`.

I have two "modulators" that are declared separately.
How can I use a `let modulator = [AKOperationEffect]()` so that I can use a `modulator.append(AKOperationEffect())` as I do for the `AKOscillator`?
When I do it, it asks me for an init parameter and I can't figure what it is. I'm sure there is a basic misunderstanding of that class that I can't figure out from the tutorials.

Thank you for all the help!

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit

class AudioEngine {

    var oscillator = [AKOscillator]()
    var dualMixer = [AKMixer]()

    init() {
        for index in 1...8 {
            oscillator.append(AKOscillator())
            oscillator[index-1].amplitude = 1
            oscillator[index-1].frequency = 110 * index
        }

        for index in 1...4 {
            dualMixer.append(AKMixer(oscillator[index-1], oscillator[index+2]))
        }

        let modulatorOne = AKOperationEffect(dualMixer[0]) { input, parameters in

            return input * ((AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: parameters[0], amplitude: 1) + 1) / 2)
        }

        let modulatorTwo = AKOperationEffect(dualMixer[1]) { input, parameters in

            return input * ((AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: parameters[0], amplitude: 1) + 1) / 2)
        }

        modulatorOne.parameters[0] = 2
        modulatorTwo.parameters[0] = 3
        modulatorOne.start()
        modulatorTwo.start()


        let mixer = AKMixer(modulatorOne, modulatorTwo)

        AudioKit.output = mixer
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Effects are different than generators in that they need inputs, which is what the initialize parameter is.  The oscillator takes no input so it can be initialized with nothing.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes of course, I well understand what you say. And the same is true for Mixers or Panners. But I can easily declare an array of them, while for OperationEffect I can't. Why? Maybe it just isn't possible? Because up to now I haven't found any example, topic or whatsoever about it in the net!

Comment: You could easily declare an array of AKOperationEffect. Your problem is that you are trying to create single instances of AKOperationEffect without the required initial parameters.  Some Swift classes require an initial argument(s) while others do not.  AKMixer can be created without an initial argument but AKOperationEffect always requires args (look at the docs at https://audiokit.io/docs/index.html and compare their init methods).  Looking the playground examples of how AKOperationEffect is used might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I understand it and I took a long (but apparently not long enough) look both at the docs and at the playground. Most probably my problem is in Swift more than in AudioKit, as I cannot manage creating arrays of closures. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I solved the problem... by avoiding the array of AKOperationEffect. While it's a better solution for my app, still i didn't learn how to use this kind of array. Moreover, up to now, I didn't find any example of it in the playground. It would have been great to have some examples in order to learn how to do it. I think it must be a problem I have with initialising these kind of nodes. I'll learn how to do it eventually... Yet I've no problems in using OperationEffect as a single (not as an array) node.